# C# Non-Generic ISet Interface

Tags: c#, list, set, contravariance

`.NET 4.0` introduced a non-generic `IList` which exposes the ability to add values to the List without needing to know the generic type. This is useful because it allows me to write a method such as the following:

```
void CreateListFromBytes(IntPtr bytes, Type outputType, out object outputObject)
{
    Type elementType = outputType.GenericTypeArguments[0];
    int numberOfElements = ReadHeaderBytes(bytes);
    bytes += Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(int));

    IList outputList = (IList) Activator.CreateInstance(outputType);
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfElements; i++)
    {
        object element = ReadDataBytes(bytes, elementType);
        bytes += Marshal.SizeOf(elementType);
        outputList.Add(element);
    }

    outputObject = outputList;
}
```

However, when I try to implement a method with a similar style for `HashSet` or `ISet`, there is not such non-generic interface I can find that exposes and `Add()` method.

I am wondering if such an interface exists that I may have missed. If not, I am wondering how I can go about adding elements to object I know for certain is `Set` (since I created it the `Activator.CreateInstance()`)

Comment: Actually `IList` pre-dates generics.

Comment: If all you need is an `Add` method, you might use `ICollection` interface. It would work for lists as well.

Comment: @tukaef Unfortunately, `HashSet` does not implement the non-generic `ICollection` interface, only the generic `ICollection<T>` one. This is really too bad as it would be perfect for my use case.

Comment: Oh, okay, so I'll undelete my answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would end up with a couple of aux types for constructing a set:

```
interface ISetBuilder 
{
    void Add(object item);
    object Build();
}

class SetBuilder<T, TSet> : ISetBuilder where TSet : ISet<T>, new() 
{
    private readonly TSet _set = new TSet();

    public void Add(object item) 
    {
        if (!(item is T typedItem)) 
        {
            throw new ArgumentException();
        }

        _set.Add(typedItem);
    }

    public object Build() => _set;
}
```

Those types then could be used like this:

```
var builderType = typeof(SetBuilder<,>).MakeGenericType(elementType, outputType);
var builder = (ISetBuilder) Activator.CreateInstance(builderType);
var element = CreateElement(...);
builder.Add(element);
var set = builder.Build();
```

And yes, this could be generalised to support lists as well. Just replace `ISet<T>` with `ICollection<T>`.

Another possible (but a bit less robust) solution is just to find and call the specific `Add` method of a set by using reflection.

Comment: Marked as accepted as it answer the question as I have written above. Sadly, as per usual, I did not ask a good enough question to fully capture my use case. In addition to `Add` I also need some means of accessing the total number of elements (e.g. `Count`). This is for use in the inverse problem where I am trying to serialize a C# `ISet` into a byte array.

Comment: Update: I can do this casting to `IEnumerable` then incremented a count as I walk through the Enumerator.

Comment: @BartKerfeld luckily, `ICollection<T>` provides `Count` property, so you could extend the builder with a similar property.